# Routing : Import a routing.yml resource with a prefix and requirements not work

Tags: symfony, routes, yaml

I try to load a localized_routes.yml inside the main routing.yml file with :

```
localized_routes:
resource: "routing_localized.yml"
prefix:   /{_locale}
requirements: { _locale : fr|es|it|de }
```

But it doesnt work at all, the requirements are not in the generated URL checks and so I can use any locale I want .... I see in the Symfony source that only the prefix are taken, not requirements or defaults values, is it an issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is an old issue, I think it will be fixed in 2.1.

Comment: Thanks dude, I didn't know its the known issue.. I will check the symfony GIT repo.

Comment: Do you know if it has been added in to the master (2.1) repo on github?